# Android to programmatically open Airplane Mode Setting page

Tags: android, android-intent, settings

I want to open Airplane Mode Setting page and for this i use the below code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS); 
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

but on samsung s5, Galaxy-note-Edge and on the other new devices Airplane
  mode Setting page is implemented as a Fragment and on the device we have option to view the settings as
  ListView ,GridView and TAB View.

On the Internet i found the option to open that particular fragment with the below code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS);
i.putExtra(":android:show_fragment", "com.android.settings.AirplaneModeSettings");
i.putExtra(":android:no_headers", true);
startActivity(i);
```

and it work fine when settings view is set set as ListView or GridView but when settings view is set as TABView then i got dialog unfortunately Settings as Stop.
Any help to overcome this problem.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Did you find any solution for enabling airplane mode in higher versions?

Comment: No, I am also finding the solution for this